# Solve $(1-x^2)y''+(1+x)y'+y=\sin2(\log(1+x))$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$\implies y''+\frac{1+x}{1-x^2}y'+\frac{1}{1-x^2}y=\sin2(\log(1+x))$

on comparing it with the standard form $y''+Py'+Qy=R$, we get $$\;P=\frac{1+x}{1-x^2}, Q=\frac{1}{1-x^2}, R=\frac{\sin2(\log(1+x))}{1-x^2}$$

I tried to solve it by the method of removing first derivative in which the solution is of the form $y=uv$ where $u=e^{-\frac{1}{2}\int pdx}$ and v is found from $\frac{d^2v}{dx^2}+Iv=s$ where $I=Q-\frac{1}{4}p^2-\frac{1}{2}\frac{dp}{dx}$ and $s=\frac{R}{u}$

then I got $\quad I = \frac{1-7x}{4(1-x)^2(1+x)},$ $\;\;\;s=\frac{\sin2(\log(1+x))}{(1+x)(1-x)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$

Now I am wondering how to solve the equation $\frac{d^2v}{dx^2}+Iv=s\quad$If $I$ reduces to some constant, then we can solve it easily. But I am stuck here.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Where does this equation come from??? It cannot be an exercise on some textbook. The solution took several minutes to *Mathematica* and is full of special function and even integral functions.

Comment: It was asked in one of the exam at graduation level in our university.